# In VBscript, place output in a text field

Tags: vbscript

Pretty basic question. I have a VBScript that asks for a computer ID and then returns its serial number. My problem is that the return is in a messagebox rather than a text field so you can't copy+paste the returned serial number.

```
MsgBox "The serial number for the specified computer is: " & SN.SerialNumber
```

Don't know much about VBscript - but I imagine there's a way to place that number in a textfield so that anyone can copy+paste it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you **can** copy the text displayed by `MsgBox` (at least, on Windows Vista). Simply click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and you'll get the following in your clipboard:

```
---------------------------

---------------------------
The serial number for the specified computer is: foobar
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it in a popup like a MsgBox, use [InputBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
Dim tmp
tmp = InputBox("The serial number for the specified computer is:",,SN.SerialNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place a text box on the page and give it an ID, then use VBScript to set properties of that field, like so:

```
Set myTextBox = Item.UserProperties.Find("myTextBoxFieldID")
myTextBox.Value = "The serial number for the specified computer is: " & SN.SerialNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this on and it will copy the output of the serial number to the clipboard:

```
'Copy output to clipboard
sText = SN.Serialnumber
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Navigate "about:blank"
Do Until objIE.ReadyState=4: WScript.Sleep 1: Loop
objIE.Document.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.SetData "Text", sText
objIE.Quit
```